# Android clip canvas.drawBitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am new to Android and I have two images one is an empty image and the other is a full image to represent a progress bar.

How can I only draw a percentage of the full image using `canvas.drawBitmap`?

I would prefer not to resize the bitmap image each time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use 2 Rects, the source Rect and the destination Rect to only draw a piece

```
//example
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.backbutton);

Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
Rect bitmapRect = new Rect(0, 0, canvasWidth -200,50);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source, bitmapRect, null);
```

a Rect is a rectangle like this

```
new Rect(topleftx,toplefty,bottomrightx,bottomrighty);
```